# select2 input text box not working with jquery ui

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I have tried to add a searchable dropdown with select2 but my input textbox not enable to get user inputs.

var Fluid =@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.Manf));

```
    $("#drpEqTypeF").select2({
    
        data: Fluid
    });
```

P.S. I'm using jquery / jquery UI

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
var Fluid =@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.Manf));
```

To this:

```
var Fluid = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.Manf))';
```

That must be the reason why you can not get the input value

Comment: No that's not the case. I think jquery UI overwrites some CSS features.